# Como poner codigo php en fwriter

Tags: php, html, fopen

Estoy haciendo un mini sistema de crear carpeta con archivos adentro, pero el html funciona perfectamente. pero al poner el codigo php deja de funcionar todo.
No encuentro ninguna informacion que me pueda ayudar.

Si alguien sabe favor de ayudarme :(

O si lo estoy haciendo mal el codigo favor de decirme :(

Codigo:

```html
?php
$fp = fopen("users/${dirname}/validar.php", "w") or die("Error al intentar abrir el archivo!");
fwrite($fp, "<?php

$miuser = 'ChristianHz';
$mipass = 'seraz90';

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
 $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
 $pass = $_POST['password'];
 if ($usuario == $miuser and $pass == $mipass ) {
        if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
         setcookie('usuario', $usuario, time()+60*60*7);
         setcookie('passowrd', $pass, time()+60*60*7);
        } 
        session_start();
         $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
         header('location:panel');
    } else {
     echo '<p>usuario o clave son incorrectos</p>';
    }
} else {
 header('location: login');
}

?>");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta reemplazando las [comillas dobles](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) `"` por [comillas simples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) `'` y escapandolas dentro de la funcion fwrite:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("users/${dirname}/validar.php", "w") or die("Error al intentar abrir el archivo!");
fwrite($fp, '<?php

$miuser = \'ChristianHz\';
$mipass = \'seraz90\';

if(isset($_POST[\'login\'])) {
    $usuario = $_POST[\'usuario\'];
    $pass = $_POST[\'password\'];
    if ($usuario == $miuser and $pass == $mipass ) {
        if (isset($_POST[\'remember\'])) {
            setcookie(\'usuario\', $usuario, time()+60*60*7);
            setcookie(\'passowrd\', $pass, time()+60*60*7);
        } 
        session_start();
        $_SESSION[\'usuario\'] = $usuario;
        header(\'location:panel\');
    } else {
        echo \'<p>usuario o clave son incorrectos</p>\';
    }
} else {
    header(\'location: login\');
}

?>');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Si usas comillas dobles, el contenido será evaluado antes de escribirse en el archivo. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$nombre = "Juan";
$variable1 = "Mi nombre es $nombre";
$variable2 = 'Mi nombre es $nombre';

echo $variable1; //Imprime: Mi nombre es Juan
echo $variable2; //Imprime: Mi nombre es $nombre
?>
```

Comment: Gracias :) me ayudo y servio bastante